# Configure maven-shade-plugin to include src/main/webapp

Tags: maven, jetty, war, embedded-jetty, maven-shade-plugin

I'm working with a simple project, with the webapp directory in the standard location (src/main/webapp). For some reason, it looks like the maven-shade-plugin doesn't include that in the final generated jar - it will only include artifacts src/main/resources by default. 
I have tried to use the following configuration, with no luck:

```
<configuration>
 <artifactSet>
  <includes>
   <include>*</include>
   <include>*:*</include>
  </includes>
 </artifactSet>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions on how to do that without having to move src/main/webapp into src/main/resources/webapp?

Thank you.

Eugen.

Comment: as far as I know this plugins is used to merge jars together, not war packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to update your build section with your resource path ?

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
           </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

EDIT

As already said, shade purpose is not to war packages.

Comment: Shade comes in handy, however, when building jar with embedded web server, where having the resources is needed.

Comment: I obviously fail to note in my own comment that wars may have embedded servers in the same way as jars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in src/main/resources/webapp or specify the appropriate location explicitly for it to be caught up properly.  Annoying, but it works.

For those asking why this kind of thing makes sense to do, it's a typical setup for a jar with an embedded web server like Jetty.

Comment: According to the accepted and upvoted answer by @Yanflea, it is not correct that you *need* to put the files inside the `src/main/resources/` folder. Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 1):

I use the resource plugin to move the webapp to the classes folder.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/webapp</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/webapp/dist</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This way I can place the folder with my webapp anywhere, define the destination directory and it is included in my shaded jar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you would like to package sources into a package. There exists a [maven-source-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) which will create a jar which contain the source files. Furthermore this is usually done during a release cycle. As already mentioned the maven-share-plugin intention is to package jar files together (their contents; keyword: ueberjar).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the war plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached to create a jar of a webapp project. You have already set `<packaging>war</packaging>`?

Answer (score 0):

What's the point in adding your webapp resources into a JAR? That's WAR-like.

Change your packaking type to `war` and it will work.

Comment: You should probably post your request for clarification as a comment to the original question, not as an answer to it.